# cannot import name importlib for rest_framework.urlpatterns

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am learning how to create a Rest API in django. in views.py, adding
 `from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns` 
is causing 
`ImportError: cannot import name importlib`. I searched that this is because I am using Django 1.9 or more maybe. But can't figure out how to solve this.
Thanks for help.

Tutorial that I am following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QW_5xCCPWFk&index=40&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK

full traceback

```
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f1b5badc500>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/sonali/Videos/rest_api_project/rest_api_project/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/urlpatterns.py", line 4, in <module>
    from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/settings.py", line 23, in <module>
    from django.utils import importlib
ImportError: cannot import name importlib
```

Python version 2.7.6

Comment: Please show the full traceback. What Python version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `django.utils.importlib` module was removed in Django 1.9. It looks as if you are running an old version of rest framework that does not support Django 1.9.

Support for Django 1.9 was added in rest framework 3.3, and the current version is 3.6.3.

If your tutorial was written for Django 1.8, then you might find it easier to complete the tutorial using Django 1.8. If it was written for an earlier version of Django that that, then it would probably be better to look for a new tutorial.